# Need to select the non-duplicate values from two table columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with city names in them. I want to check the first table against the second table and if the first table does not contain a city name in the second table then select it to display. So if the city is in both tables, then do not display it.

I know that I can do this to find the ones that match:

```
WHERE table1.city=table2.city
```

But when I try to use this for things that dont match:

```
Where table1.city!=table2.city
```

I still get the cities that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `city_name` 
FROM `first_table`
WHERE `city_name` NOT IN (SELECT `city_name` FROM `second_table`)
```

Will select city names from the first table that are not in second table.

Comment: This works great, just takes really long. ^^  Thank you so much!