# SQL query to find non duplicate values in two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`. In both tables `msg_id` is common.

I have written the following query:

```
select alert.MSG_ID, alert.ACTION, 
       alert.ALERT_ID, alert.CONTACT_DETAIL,
       alert.TRXREFNUMBER, alert.TARGET_SYSTEM,
       log.MSG_ID, log.ACTION, log.ERR_CODE, log.CONTACT_DETAIL 
from bnea.table1 alert, 
     bnea.table2 log
where not exists (select a.MSG_ID 
                  from bnea.table2 
                  where alert.MSG_ID = log.MSG_ID);
```

However it is not working. When I execute the above query it cross joins all records.

Anyone have any experience with a query like this or similar?

Comment: You can use DISTINCT

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377418/need-to-select-the-non-duplicate-values-from-two-table-columns, hope this will help

Comment: where not exists !! this part of your query maybe cause of fail. i thinck better u shoud do this : where MSG_ID not exists ... .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format of query to get output without any duplicate result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,.....columnN 
FROM table_name
WHERE [condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included a CROSS JOIN (by accident), your original query (reformatted):

```
SELECT
      alert.MSG_ID
    , alert.ACTION
    , alert.ALERT_ID
    , alert.CONTACT_DETAIL
    , alert.TRXREFNUMBER
    , alert.TARGET_SYSTEM
    , log.MSG_ID
    , log.ACTION
    , log.ERR_CODE
    , log.CONTACT_DETAIL
FROM bnea.table1 alert
   , bnea.table2 log     --<<<<< this is a cross join !!!
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  a.MSG_ID
            FROM bnea.table2
            WHERE alert.MSG_ID = log.MSG_ID
      );
```

It should read:

```
SELECT
      alert.MSG_ID
    , alert.ACTION
    , alert.ALERT_ID
    , alert.CONTACT_DETAIL
    , alert.TRXREFNUMBER
    , alert.TARGET_SYSTEM
FROM bnea.table1 alert
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM bnea.table2 log
            WHERE alert.MSG_ID = log.MSG_ID
      );
```

Notes:

1. Don't use commas to separate tables in the FROM clause, this trick forces you to think about the joins you need and ALWAYS use ANSI syntax for joins.
2. It isn't necessary to return a column for the EXISTS condition. Some use SELECT NULL, others prefer SELECT 1 or SELECT *. I favour SELECT NULL

Answer (score 0):

using FULL OUTER JOIN as followed?

```
SELECT
      alert.MSG_ID
    , alert.ACTION
    , alert.ALERT_ID
    , alert.CONTACT_DETAIL
    , alert.TRXREFNUMBER
    , alert.TARGET_SYSTEM
    , log.MSG_ID
    , log.ACTION
    , log.ERR_CODE
    , log.CONTACT_DETAIL
FROM bnea.table1 alert FULL OUTER JOIN bnea.table2 log ON(alert.MSG_ID = log.MSG_ID)
WHERE log.MSG_ID <> alert.MSG_ID
```